# Should I seal this floor or should I just put down vapor barrier before tiling?

Tags: flooring, tile, subfloor, mold

I had some water compromise a vanity, leading to its removal. There was a void in the floor where it was originally tiled around, so the entire floor will be retiled.

Upon demolition, I noticed some mold under the old vapor barrier. Having some kilz remaining from another job, I’m considering sealing the floor before putting down the first layer. Is this a good idea or a bad one?

I have already thoroughly sprayed the floor and mold with bleach to kill it.

Pictures for reference, the white area was sealed when I removed the vanity...

[image: area]

[image: one section]

[image: section two]

Comment: In the future try not to use bleach. Instead use an actual modicide/fungicide

Comment: It certainly won't hurt anything if you "seal" (i.e. paint) it.